# How to use arrow function to alert something

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I have this image with that funcion onclick

```
<img src="assets/images/logo.svg" id="logo" onclick="alertPlay()">
```

If I make the following function shouldn't it work?

```
const alertPlay => alert("play");
```

if not, maybe I'm just confused about the arrow functions in general.

Also, isn't there a shorthand, like

```
<img src="assets/images/logo.svg" id="logo" onclick="alert('play')">
```

Comment: Use `const alertPlay => () => alert("play");`

Comment: Should be `const alertPlay = () => alert("play");`. Check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Read documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body

Comment: ??? what edit are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax. `() => alert("play");` is function body. You need to assign it to a variable using `=`.
OP asked in comment: *Also, why should I put the `()` between the `=` and the `=>`*:
Because its correct syntax described by [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Basic_syntax)

> The parameter list for a function with no parameters should be written with a pair of parentheses.

```js
const alertPlay = () => alert("play");
```

```html
<img src="assets/images/logo.svg" id="logo" onclick="alertPlay()">
```

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain all the pieces of the arrow function that you can use.

```
const funcName = (parameters) => alert('message');
```

const funcName represents the name of the function & that it's immutable, raising an error if you try to reassign its value.

= (parameters) => alert('message');

assigns funcName the value, first is a parenthesis for all the arguments of the function, the arrow is used instead of function keyword before the parenthesis and alert('message'); is the javascript you want to run. Your javascript code might be longer & then you can use brackets{}.

Working example:

```
<img src="assets/images/logo.svg" id="logo" onclick="alertPlay('play')">

const alertPlay = (message) => alert(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

## A bit newer:

You need to use like:

```
const alertPlay = () => () => alert("play");
```

And in your html, it should just be: (No parentheses required)

```
onclick="alertPlay"
```

If you want to pass the dynamic value rather than just `play`, you'll need to use like:

```
const alertPlay = (str) => () => alert(str);
```

HTML:

```
onclick="alertPlay('play')"
```

The second arrow function block is to pass event if you would like:

```
const alertPlay = (str) => (e) => {
  console.log(e, str);
}
```

## Actual answer that fits your interest:

BTW, `() => () => {}` is a [public class method](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/). Otherwise, you may use inline arrow function like:

```
onclick="() => alertPlay('play')"
```

JS:

```
const alertPlay = (str) => alert(str);
```

Or without any parameters:

```
const alertPlay = () => alert('play');
```

HTML:

```
onclick="alertPlay()"
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `function` would be

```
const alertPlay = (message) => alert(message);
```

And the `HTML`

```
<img src="assets/images/logo.svg" id="logo" onclick="alertPlay('play')">
```

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I didn't downvote, but before I edited, it was `const alertPlay => (message) => alert(message);`